# streamline jquery autosave text

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosave

```
$("textarea").bind("keyup", function () {

            var keyName = $(this).attr("data-rkn-keyName");
            autoSave(keyName, this.value);

    });

    function autoSave(key, value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/SaveLookup",
            type: "POST",
            data: ("keyName=" + key + "&value=" + value),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('#saved-signal').show().fadeOut(1500);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have a few textareas on a page and I'd like for them to autosave user input.  The data being edited is a set of key/value pairs, the textarea being the value and the textarea's 'data-rkn-keyName' attribute being the key.

So the above code kinda works but if the user types fast it won't catch the last character or two.  So I altered it like so:

```
$("textarea").bind("keydown", function () {
    var keyName = $(this).attr("data-rkn-keyName");
    var keyValue = $(this).value;
        setTimeout(function (keyName, keyValue) {
            autoSave(keyName, keyValue);
        }, 2000);
    });
```

So, adding the timer breaks it, autoSave does get called but I have a feeling the vars are losing their values.....possibly something to do with variable scope.  So that is a minor issue I can work out...more importantly (and the purpose for my post), question: will I be instantiating a new timer object and an ajax call (=database hit) every time a key is pressed?  Or does setTimeout reset same object if you call it repeatedly?

What I'd like is to call the autoSave function a second or two after a keystroke is pressed but only if no keystrokes are pressed during that time...in other words, if the user pauses for 2 seconds...fire the save function.

Or maybe there's a better way to do autosave?

thank you

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` accepts an anonymous function without any arguments. When you included `keyName` and `keyValue` as input arguments, the anonymous function will receive nil for both arguments. Just remove the arguments, and the values will be passed successfully.

```
$("textarea").bind("keydown", function () {
    var keyName = $(this).attr("data-rkn-keyName");
    var keyValue = $(this).value;
    setTimeout(function () {
        autoSave(keyName, keyValue);
    }, 2000);
});
```